# How to make new button for can sort post?

Tags: strapi

[image: strapi/src/admin/app.js][image: strapi/src/admin/extensions/components/SortingPublish/index.js]

from this picture is my code for create button.

[image: When I clicked button.]

When I clicked button I see blank object. why?

I want to make button for can click and sorting post like sorting click in table.

[image: I make button for can click]

From this picture
I'm done for created button but I dont know about what i should to do next step like

- how to make function for sort post?
- how to access data or something?
- I want to show only published post.

thanks you so much.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)